# Get the local emergency phone number for an iOS device

Tags: ios, telephony

I need obtain the local emergency number in iOS so that I can display it. How can I do this?

Comment: As in the emergency number for the user's locale?

Comment: yes, how is this possible?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, have you figured It out?